# Intellisense do not find actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have added new route to routes table to omit controller names from url. Everything works fine at runtime but at design time I have noticed that Intellisense do not gives any suggestions and marks Actions(MyActionName in my demo) as not found when I use `@Html.ActionLink("Label", "MyActionName")` method. Is such Intellisense behaviour normal?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Custom",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

);
```

Comment: Intelisence gives suggestion for Actions while typing in ActionLink method but not in my case above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. For which method Intellisense doesn't show up? In this case you can only expect Intellisense for the `ActionLink` helper when you type `@Html.` in your view and that's the best you could hope for out of the box:

[image]

The arguments of this method are just magic strings, so don't expect them to show up in Intellisense.

If you want strong typing and Intellisense you could use either [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) which provides strongly typed versions of this helper which allows you to do this:

```
@(Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(x => x.MyActionName(), "label"))
```

or [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC):

```
@Html.ActionLink("label", T4MVC.Home.MyActionName())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me Intellisense never worked for an action so what I do is I write the controller name first and  then I get the full intellisense to the all the actions available within that controller.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Link text","","Home")
```

In the above case I just put "", an empty string for the action and after comma I got full intellisense for my controllers. After writing/selecting my controller name when I click between the quotation marks for the action name I get full intellisense for the actions available within specified controller(in the above code,Home).

I am not sure thats the best way but its working for me.